# To construct probability function

Tags: probability

Question:

*The coin is tossed twice. Variable Y is the number of the heads. Construct probability function of Y.*

So I know that I can get either 0, 1 or 2 heads. The probabilities for these heads are: 
$$ 0 =0.25$$
$$1 =0.50$$
$$2= 0.25$$

Right?

But how to get the probability function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is basically it.   Just make it presentable.   The probability mass function is a piecewise function.

$$\mathsf P(Y{=}y)=\begin{cases}0.25&:& y=0\\0.50&:& y=1\\0.25&:& y=2\\0&:&\text{elsewise}\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

You are done, suppose the probability of getting a head is $p$, then $Y \sim Bin(2,p)$ where $$P(Y=y) = \begin{cases}\binom{2}{y}p^y(1-p)^{2-y} & y\in \{0,1,2\}\\ 0 & \text{Otherwise} \end{cases}$$

Remark:
Avoid writing stuff like $0=0.25$ though I know what you mean.